# Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\mu$-$p$-mean and $f_n \rightarrow g$ $\mu$.a.e. What can be said about $f$ and $g$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal E, \mu)$ be a measure-space, $p \in (0,\infty)$ and $f,g, f_1, f_2, \ldots \in \mathcal M(\mathcal E)$.

I've been wondering about the following:

Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\mu$-$p$-mean and $f_n \rightarrow g$ $\mu$.a.e.

What can be said about $f$ and $g$ then ?

From the above I know $\int_X |f_n - f|^p d \mu \rightarrow 0$ and $\{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n \neq g \} \subseteq A \in \mathcal E$
 and $\mu(A) = 0$.

I also know that if $f = g$ $\mu$.a.e then $f_n \rightarrow g$ in $\mu$-$p$-mean.

Comment: Do you remember a theorem about subsequences of $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_p$-convergent sequences?

Comment: Yes, why ? There exist a subsequence that converge to some $g \in \mathcal M(\mathcal E) $?

Comment: Not just to _some_ $g$, to a very specific one.

Comment: My theorem doesn't state anything about uniqueness.

Comment: Okay, which theorem were you thinking of?

Comment: Just a theorem saying that if $(f_n)$ is Cauchy then there exist an increasing sequence $n_1, n_2, ...$ of natural numbers s.t $(f_{n_i})$ converges to some $f$.

Comment: It should be explicitly mentioned in the theorem which $f$ that is, but you can also find that out from the proof. It's the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_p$-limit of the sequence